# What to use as language and region for Norway in sitemap.xml?

Tags: locale, xml-sitemap

I am unsure what I should use as language/region for norway in my sitemap.xml file. Should I use `nb-no` or `nn-no` or just `no`?

```
<url>
<loc>https://somedomain.com/</loc>
<xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="no" href="https://somedomain.no/" />
<priority>1.0</priority>
<lastmod>2022-09-05T00:21:02+02:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
</url>
```

It seems Google recommends that it should not only be `no`:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions#language-codes